# clarify R licenses: machine learning models, developed with R in Azure, possible for commercial use?

Tags: license-compatibility, gpl-3, license-recommendation, commercial, proprietary-code

i want to estimate *machine learning models with R* and i need to use it in a production environment, i'll work with *Azure Datascience Virtual Machine or Azure Machine Learning*.

If i use , for ex., *caret* library for models and *tidyverse* for etl, can i have problem with licenses,
i read taht R libraries for the major have GPL3 licenses?

I found that with *python* there aren't problems if i use ml models in productions and commercial use, for examples scikit-learn:

> It is licensed under a permissive simplified BSD license

What about R that have GPL3 licenses for major packages? i read

> "This General Public License does not permit incorporating your program into proprietary programs"

This means that licenses can make me problems for commercial use?
What does using a model developed in R where the library has a GPL3 license entails?

hope it' clear my question
thanks in advance
have a nice day
MC